# A Sci-Fi novel with flying police robots scanning the city

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for the book title (perhaps it was a short novel, my memory here is cloudy) in which the main hero was wanted by law enforcement and there have been flying police robots / drones who scanned the city.

In the same book, there was a story about a high-caste of people who have been creating new continents and islands.

Comment: Are you sure this was a single novel and not an anthology?

Comment: @Spencer unfortunately, I am not sure at all. It might have been either.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You haven't given much detail, but the little you have given matches the novel [The Diamond Age](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1181) by Neal Stephenson.

One of the main plots in the story has Nell, a girl under 10 years old, and her older brother Harv, hiding in a park from hovering robots that prevent homeless people from camping there.  This is on an island grown using nanotechnological methods by a phyle (much like a tribe or a nation/state) named New Atlantis, who are relatively wealthy and who style their society after Victorian England.

Comment: Hi and welcome! Great first answer! Please do stay a while, and take the [tour]. Share and enjoy!

Comment: @Sotto Voce, I don't know how much I could thank you - this is exactly it!

Comment: That's amazing, getting this from as little you had to go on. I've read the same book, but wouldn't have thought of it. Great job!

Comment: "high-caste of people who have been creating new continents and islands" was enough; but you beat me to it.